# intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra at onReceive broadcast returns List with nulls android

Tags: android, arraylist, broadcast, intentservice

I have IntentService which fetch (in many iteration) details from the net (flight details for example), then create objects(parcable) out of this data and store the objects in an ArrayList. when there is no more data to fetch the service will stop.

in each iteration I'm sending the Arraylist (**via a BroadCast**) with the so far fetched data to an Activity (which run on the main thread) to present the so far fetched data. when I prepare the ArrayList (at the **service**) and fill it with the flight object everything is good (lets say I have filled it with 17 FlightObjects), but in the **OnReceive**  method of the broadcast (**in the main thread**), when trying to get the array out of the intent something happens that corrupting the array, ill get an array list which his size 17 and the first object is indeed FlightOject, **but the rest of the objects are null**.

that's the code on the **Service** for sending the Broadcast

```
private void sendMyBroacast(ArrayList<SkyScannerFlightObj> skyScannerFlights) {

    try{
        //sending back the arrayList to the main thread
        Intent broadCastIntent=new Intent();
        broadCastIntent.setAction(SearchFlights.BROADCAST_ACTION);
        broadCastIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("flightsArr", skyScannerFlights);
        sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

that's how the array looks on debuging on the service:

[image]

that's the code on the **Main UI** for receiving the intent :

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        ArrayList<SkyScannerFlightObj> skyScannerFlights =extras.getParcelableArrayList("flightsArr");
        searchFlightAct.displaySkyScannerFlights(skyScannerFlights);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

that's how the array looks on debuging on the Main Thread:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Might be a bug in your Parcelable implementation; can you post the code of `SkyScannerFlightObj` ?

Comment: @BenP. Indeed it was the Parcelable object, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the write function in the Parcelable object. I comment two lines there and forgot to uncomment these lines.
after uncomment these lines the getArralylistExtra from the intent works as expected